# How do you specify Big-Theta of an algorithm when the Big-O and Big-Omega are different?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I understand that if `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))` and `f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))`, we can conclude that `f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))`.

But what if we have an algorithm where the Big-O and Big-Ω are different? For example `f(n) ∈ O(n^2)` and `f(n) ∈ Ω(n)`. Then what would be its Big-Theta notation?

To me, it seems that both `f(n) ∈ Θ(n^2)` and `f(n) ∈ Θ(n)` would be technically correct claims. I suspect I might have misunderstood something and I would appreciate if anyone could clarify this.

Comment: "would be technically correct claims": no, they would be technically wrong. You see it by comparing the definitions.

Comment: Usually, that happens either because your $O(f(n))$ is an overestimation (e.g. you show $O(n^2)$, but with a more rigorous analysis, you'd see it's actually $O(n)$), or it happens because $\Omega(g(n))$ is an underestimation (e.g. you had $\Omega(n)$, but you find a case worse than before that takes time $\Omega(n^2)$).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

- either the Big-$\Theta$ lies somewhere between the Big-$O$ and Big-$\Omega$ but we can't tell from the given;
- or there is no Big-$\Theta$ expression at all (but we can't tell from the given).

E.g.

$T_n=O(n^2), T_n=\Omega(n)$ and $T_n=\Theta(n^2)$ are all true,

where $T_n$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ triangular number, and

$n^2\cos^2(n)+n\sin^2(n)=O(n^2),n^2\cos^2(n)+n\sin^2(n)=\Omega(n)$, but there is no $\Theta$.